# Signing a verified commit with Eclipse (MacOS) to GitHub (GPG)

Tags: eclipse, macos, github, gnupg

Started using Eclipse (2018-12) and noticed that none of my commits have a verified signature when pushing to GitHub.

Is there a way to have Eclipse sign my commits to GitHub with my public GPG key?

```
$ gpg version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.13
```

```
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1
```

**UPDATE 3/22/2019** -
Got the 2019-03 (4.11.0). Still no luck with getting Eclipse to sign a verified commit. I see the Sign Commit icon (lock) in the Git Staging tab, and I get the following dialog on commit.

> Unable to find a GPG key for signing. Configure GPG key with committer email address, set user.signingKey or disable commit signing.

I am able to sign commits in OSX Terminal, and my Eclipse configuration preferences for Team>Git>Configuration show:

User Settings tab:

```
 user:
    name = [myname]
    email = "[myname]@users.noreply.github.com"
    signingkey = [mykey]
```

What I don't see in Eclipse is a place to enter (which is in .gitconfig):

```
commit:
    gpgsign = true
```

Answer (score 5):

**Starting with the Eclipse IDE 2019-03** (4.11), which will be released on March 20, 2019, **Git commits can be signed with a GPG key**.

In the *Git Staging* view, there is an icon with a lock to enable signing:

[image]

If in your Git configuration `commit.gpgsign` is set to `true`, the button is pressed by default. As EGit does not delegate to the command line, but uses JGit (which is a Git implementation in Java) it does not matter which version of the command line Git is installed or if it is installed at all. To access the key store Bouncy Castle is used which means `gpg.program` in the Git configuration is ignored.

In [milestone 3 of the upcoming Eclipse release 2019-03](http://%20https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-03/m3) signing should alread work (on Windows there is a bug which has already been fixed; see my [bug report for a workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544797)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess I'll have to wait till 3/20/2019 for my signed commits in Eclipse. In the meantime, back to Terminal!

Comment: Got the update. I see the lock. Still unable to Sign verified commit. See modified answer.

Comment: @CarlosFMeneses I'm sorry it doesn't work for you under macOS. Currently, the location of the key store is not configurable and expected in `~/.gnupg`. Please check if this directory exists and can be read as normal user. Otherwise, try to remove `user.signingkey` so that the key lookup is done via name and e-mail. Like other setting the `commit.gpgsign` setting can be done in the global Git configuration or in the `.git/config` of a repository. But this setting is only for the default enabling of the lock button. [Watch my video showing this on Windows](https://youtu.be/2LZ6rxiLp-I?t=122).

Comment: `~/.gnupg` directory exists and is readable. Tried removing `usr.signinkey`, which only existed in .gitconfig. Loved the video. Subscribed.

Comment: @howlger, I'm getting the same problem, but I'm using ubuntu. I can sign commits outside eclipse but not with jgit/egit. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of JGit in your Eclipse plugin dependency list: if it is 5.3, then yes, it should be possible.

This is followed by [JGit issue 382212](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382212#c14).
A few weeks ago, [changeset 133402](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/133402/) introduces the concept of a GpgSigner which will sign commits. The GpgSigner will be of a specific implementation (eg., Bouncycastle or OpenPgP executable).

That might be too recent for the Eclipse version you are using though.

Comment: JGit/EGit 5.3 has not yet been released. Not all JGit features will be used by EGit. Some JGit features are implemented to be used on server side, e.g. for [Gitiles used by Google](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/).

Answer (score 0):

In the Git Staging view, there is an icon with a lock, please click on the lock before going for commit and push, you will not see the error and it will push to the git repo.